# Gradle build only one module

Tags: gradle

I have a multiple module gradle build. I want to execute targets for one module using root.
Ex :

```
gradle build -Pmodule=ABC
gradle jar -Pmodule=ABC
gradle test -Pmodule=ABC
gradle compileJava -Pmodule=ABC
gradle customTask -Pmodule=ABC
etc.
```

So every target can be run from the root specifying the module.
Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: `if (project.hasProperty('module') && module.equals('ABC')) { // execute module ABC } ...`. This is what you want to achieve?

Comment: @pepuch, could you please clarify? I would like to push updates to my app which has a aar in it but to make it build only the changes in the app without rebuilding the library.

Answer (score 423, accepted):

To execute a task of a specific subproject, specify its *task path*. For example:

```
gradle :ABC:build
```

The leading `:` stands for the root project. `ABC` is the subproject, and `build` a task in that project.

Comment: How can you control via config rather than command line to only assemble one subproject out of many? For Google's Release Pipelines, it fires off a "gradle clean assemble" in the root project. For me, that tries to build the AppEngine AND Android builds. The Release Pipeline will fail on the Android build as it doesn't have the SDK installed, understandable for a transient machine. Also, it doesn't look like Release Pipelines offers any configuration options either.

Comment: In my case the root project still inspected and fires error messages I don't want to deal with at this time. Very annoying.

Comment: `gradle :ABC:clean :ABC:build`

Comment: gradle build -p moduleA   is better, it will handle the module's dependencies.

Comment: Suppose i want to run multiple sub-projects combined together with root project but not all sub-projects then what should be the command for the same?

Answer (score 117):

Found a quick way

```
gradle build -p moduleA
```

moduleA is the module's directory.

Above command builds a `moduleA` and all its submodules, and `moduleA` should be its path

Comment: Above command build a moudleA and all it's submodule, and moduleA should be it's path         `gradle build -p path\pathSt\moduleA`

Comment: I have a wrapper for subprojects that has no gradle file of its own. Unlike the selected answer, this works for me. Also thanks for clarification in comment, could you add it to the answer?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer; `gradle :ABC:build` requires every task to be qualified.

Comment: Lets say there are 3 modules, M1, M2 and M3 and if M1 has M2 in its dependency and if I want to build M1 without touching M3 then how can that be achieved?

Answer (score 50):

On Mac OS, the only variant which is working with me :

```
./gradlew  ABC:build
```

`ABC` is the name of module

( It might be working on Linux too )

Answer (score 12):

[image]

If your IDE is Android Studio ,there is a simple way.Just choose the module folder you want to compile ,then click Build and choose Make Module 'your module folder'.

Answer (score 1):

In *Android Studio*, if you need to generate a signed bundle or apk, you can choose the needed module in *Module* select field: **Build > Generate Signed Bundle or APK > choose Android App Bundle or APK > Module**

[image: choice]