# Android Studio Build only 1 Module

Tags: android, android-studio

Can someone tell me how to build a module,i.e Only Single Module ? There is only one option to build the whole project,but If in the project there are multiple modules then how to build those separately ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976214/gradle-build-only-one-module

Answer (score 5):

Select the module you want to build or the build.gradle file itself in the project view.  (Other views might also work; I think what's important is that whatever has focus, either in the project view, editor or elsewhere, will be the module available for building.)

Now go to Build in the menu bar.  There should be an option to make that individual module directly under the option to make the whole project.

(I have only tested this in versions 1.5 and 2.0).

Comment: It seems like it should behave this way, but the build still fails with 72 errors from the unrelated module. (The module I'm trying to build is not dependent on the errory module.)