# Android project and Gradle: assemble a single module

Tags: android, command-line, android-studio, gradle

I have an Android Studio project that contains several sub-projects (aka: modules).
I would like to build some of these sub-projects **from the command line**.

I read on the Android dev guide that you can build your project by simply running

```
gradlew.bat assembleDebug
```

from the command line, however this always builds the **entire** project (all the modules)
I just want to assemble a single module, how do I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
gradlew.bat assembleDebug -a -b path/to/module/build.gradle
```

`-a` only builds the component and does not rebuild its dependencies

Use `-b` to specify another Gradle build file. In this case, the module's instead of the top-level build.gradle.

If you weren't using the Gradle wrapper, you could alternatively just `cd` to the module directory and run `gradle assembleDebug -a` there.

Answer (score 19):

Another way to do this is:

```
gradlew.bat :myModule:assembleDebug
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16987319/1807627