# How to do an assembleRelease for a single module in android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to do an assembleRelease for a single module. I have already red this [Gradle build only one module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976214/gradle-build-only-one-module), where the approach is to put on a terminal 
`./gradlew :nameOfModule:action`(assembleRelease on this case). I need to know if I am doing it right, because it should be generating an apk but instead what I get is a `.dex` document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android studio provides an ability to do **Gradle** tasks via a user interface.
Push a "**Gradle**" button in a top right corner of the Android Studio, in a pinned window select a `moduleName -> Tasks - > build -> assembleRelease`

You can find a generated **.apk** file in `%PROJECT_ROOT%/Module/name/build/outputs/apk` directory.

[image]