# Gradle: How to only build certain apps in project

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I'm working on a project that takes forever to build since it consists of many subprojects.
How can I tell gradlew only to build certain projects but not all?

Here are the respective lines in my `Makefile`

```
    ${PWD}/gradlew assemble 
    ${PWD}/gradlew assembleDebug 
    ${PWD}/gradlew bundle
```

which seems to loop over everything. I also looked at the "project.level" build.gradle file, but I cannot see anything referring to the individual subfolders / subprojects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle build only one module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976214/gradle-build-only-one-module)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out

```
${PWD}/gradlew assembleDebug
```

was enough. build is still slow, but it's a small step in the right direction...