# How to build/create APK from selected app only in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: app option]

here is my project that has 2 app
then I want to build the APK by choosing Build - Build APK(s)
but both app projects were created.

[image]

how to create APK for only 1 chosen app?

Comment: You can use gradle to build only one module: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976214/gradle-build-only-one-module